# locally site works fine, but remotely (deployed) it has to be included in the compatibility settings

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, internet-explorer

a website made in .net/c#/html/css

**locally works fine in internet explorer**

**but remotely (deployed) it has to be included in the compatibility settings of internet explorer!?**

**any one has a clue why? or how to find out?**

the general issue is that for example some devexpress pagination does not work and some buttons do not work, and links don't do anything when clicked, etc...

but like i said localy - started from visual studio in internet explorer, no problems. deployed - in internet explorer it has these issues but chrome is just fine for example.

Comment: Hi, can you provide more information? You mention that in chrome it works fine when deployed but not on IE. Can you tell us what exactly is not working. you mention links don't work when you click on them. What are the links suppose to do otherwise. Try to determine the difference between chrome and IE once deployed using the dev tools.

Comment: Probably need to update/patch ASP.NET on the server. Their crack software for a while didn't work right with IE 10, like button click events or other JavaScript functions.

Comment: @smk1992 links such as sign out, buttons such as going to another page, dropdown in the header for choosing a language, etc... everything like that does not work unless in compatibility mode

Comment: @MikeSmithDev hard to get the customer to upgrade the .net, but i can try. do you think that can really cause this? oh and it's ie11 that has these issues.

Comment: @b0x0rz It depends on your specific error, but I know for a fact that this can be an issue, as I experienced it on my own site. And oh yeah [here is the article on Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869299(v=vs.85).aspx). Also, if you can't ensure your server that you are deploying to is up-to-date, then you will probably run into more issues in the future.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev if you make your last comment and answer i can accept it. It is EXACTLY that what you linked. <3 thnx a lot

Comment: So I'm guess you have assigned a click event for the sign out. Can you test if it getting triggered or not. Does it get triggered and errors out or does it not get triggered at all?

Comment: @smk1992 yeah the error is _doPostBack is undefined as MikeSmithDev linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likely culprit is that ASP.NET is not properly detecting Internet Explorer, as detailed [in this Microsoft post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869299(v=vs.85).aspx). One way to tell is you will get a `_doPostBack is undefined JavaScript` error.

To resolve this issue, do one of the following:

1. Revise the application to use feature detection, rather than browser detection (preferred).
2. Update the [ASP.NET browser definition files](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=245711).